# Powershell Listview OwnerDrawFixed custom colours

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to get my head around getting powershell to draw a listview object using the 'OwnerDraw' property.

From what I understand, I should be putting the handle in the Listview object, I presume I do this by using the command for the header for example:

```
$listview_DrawColumnHeader
```

Then from there you draw the items, however the only examples I can find on the internet are C#, which I have no clue how to adapt to powershell ! Is there anyway I can run the C# code inside powershell and let C# draw the listview? Or is this not efficient?

The reason I'm doing this is because I have a form which uses colours similar to 'Cerulean', which doesn't look good whilst using the standard blue 'highlight' colour. I've got lots of powershell GUI's and I know it's possible to customise this, so I'd like to learn how to, then I can start creating GUI's that look a bit more professional !

Although I've got experience with using the register-objectevent cmdlet, I've not got a lot of experience with C# and placing handles within object.

Any help would be appreciated !

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've created a WinForms ListView object, set the OwnerDraw property to $true and subscribe to the DrawColumnHeader event e.g:

```
$listView.OwnerDraw = $true
$listView.add_DrawColumnHeader({ 
    $eventArgs.DrawBackground()
    $eventArgs.Graphics.DrawString($eventArgs.SubItem.Text, $listView.Font, ...)
})
```

See this [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx) for more info.